# How to mount volume from container to host in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a question regarding the whole data volume process in Docker. Basically here are two Dockerfiles and their respective run commands:

**Dockerfile 1 -**

```
# Transmission over Debian
#
# Version 2.92

FROM debian:testing

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install nano \
    && apt-get -y install transmission-daemon transmission-common transmission-cli \
    && mkdir -p /transmission/config /transmission/watch /transmission/download

ENTRYPOINT ["transmission-daemon", "--foreground"]
CMD ["--config-dir", "/transmission/config", "--watch-dir", "/transmission/watch", "--download-dir", "/transmission/download", "--allowed", "*", "--no-blocklist", "--no-auth", "--no-dht", "--no-lpd", "--encryption-preferred"]
```

**Command 1 -**

```
docker run --name transmission -d -p 9091:9091 -v C:\path\to\config:/transmission/config -v C:\path\to\watch:/transmission/watch -v C:\path\to\download:/transmission/download transmission
```

**Dockerfile 2 -**

```
# Nginx over Debian
#
# Version 1.10.3

FROM debian:testing

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install nano \
    && apt-get -y install nginx

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Command 2 -**

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 80:80 -v C:\path\to\config:/etc/nginx -v C:\path\to\html:/var/www/html nginx
```

So, the weird thing is that the first dockerfile and command works as intended. Where the docker daemon mounts a directory from the container to the host. So, I am able to edit the configuration files as I please and they will be persisted to the container on a restart.

However, as for the second dockerfile and command it doesn't seem to be working. I know if you go to the Docker Volume documentation it says that volume mounts are only intended to go one-way, from host-to-container, but how come the Transmission container works as intended, while the Nginx container doesn't?

P:S - I'm running *Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Build 14393* as my host and *Version 17.03.0-ce-win1 (10300) Channel: beta* as my Docker version.

Edit - Just to clarify. I'm trying to get the files from inside the Nginx container to the host. The first container (Transmission) works in that regard, by using a data volume. However, for the second container (Nginx), it doesn't want to copy the files in the mounted directory from inside the container to the host. Everything else is working though, it does successfully start.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Does the container fail to start? Are the local files appearing in the mounted directory but not updating? Is there anything at all in the mounted directories?

Comment: @Matt I'm trying to get the files from inside the Nginx container to the host. The first container (Transmission) works in that regard, by using a data volume. However, for the second container (Nginx), it doesn't want to copy the files in the mounted directory from inside the container to the host. Everything else is working though, it does successfully start.

Comment: Please update your question with these information.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) don't copy data from the container > host. Host volumes mount over the top of what's in the container/image, so they effectively replace what's in the container with what's on the host.

```
docker run -v /path/to/hostdir:/var/whatever myimage
```

[A standard or "named" volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) *will* copy the existing data from the container image when the volume is first created. These volumes are created by launching a container with the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) command in it's `Dockerfile` or with the `--volume` or `--mount` docker command options specifying a name instead of a path.

```
docker run -v myvolume:/var/whatever myimage
```

By default this is data stored in a "local" volume, "local" being on the Docker host. In your case that is on the VM running Docker rather than your Windows host so might not be easily accessible to you.

You could be mistaking transmission auto generating files in a blank directory for a copy?

If you really need the keep the VM Host > container mappings then you might have to copy the data manually:

```
docker create --name nginxcopy nginx
docker cp nginxcopy:/etc/nginx C:\path\to\config
docker cp nginxcopy:/var/www/html C:\path\to\html
docker rm nginxcopy
```

And then you can map the populated host directories into the container and they will have the default data the image came with.

Comment: Could you explain the standard volumes a bit more? What do you mean by, "copy the existing data in the container image to a new volume?"

Comment: I've expanded the section a bit. Basically when docker creates a new volume for a Dockerfile `VOLUME` or `docker run -v volume:/wherever` it will populate the volume with whatever already exists in the target mount point in the container image (`/wherever`).  It's the behaviour your looking for but you don't get to specify a location on the host and it's not mapped to Windows.

Comment: Okay, that makes a bit more sense, but I'm still confused on one thing. How come the Transmission container copies the files to the directory on the host, but the Nginx container doesn't?

Comment: @Cat Trying moving all the config somewhere else and starting the container again. Does transmission recreate the config when it's missing?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, it's a brand new config. Meaning it doesn't have the same settings as the one that I moved.

Comment: So when you first mapped the host volume into the transmission container, transmission created a new config in there.  I assume you have edited in those changes since you first brought the container up?

Comment: Yes and yes. Basically when you create a new container with the Transmission Dockerfile it creates a new config in the mapped host directory. I totally understand your logic of copying the files and mounting a host volume. However, the Transmission container is really throwing me off. TL;DR - Is there any special reason the Transmission container is behaving this way? And can I replicate that behavior to the Nginx container?

Comment: The reason is the transmission application is programmed to do that, it's nothing to do with Docker.  Nginx is not programmed that way. You could write a script that checks if there is no config and copies defaults in from somewhere else, before launching nginx.

Comment: You mentioned the "host volumes" is it the same as [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)?

Answer (score 31):

The host volume will not copy data like a named volume will. However, you can create a named volume that performs a bind mount, which will then have the data initialization properties of any other named volume. The only prerequisite of a bind mount over a host volume is that the directory must exist in advance, docker will not create it for you like it does with a host volume. Here are three different examples of how to create a bind mount volume:

```bash
      # create the volume in advance
      $ docker volume create --driver local \
          --opt type=none \
          --opt device=/home/user/test \
          --opt o=bind \
          test_vol
    
      # create on the fly with --mount
      $ docker run -it --rm \
        --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/home/user/test \
        foo
```

```yaml
      # inside a docker-compose file
      ...
      volumes:
        bind-test:
          driver: local
          driver_opts:
            type: none
            o: bind
            device: /home/user/test
      ...
```

So in your example with a `docker run` command, you can use the mount syntax:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 80:80 \
  --mount type=volume,dst=/etc/nginx,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/c/path/to/config \
  --mount type=volume,dst=/var/www/html,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/c/path/to/html \
  nginx
```

The only part that may need adjusting is the windows path names inside the Linux VM that docker runs in HyperV.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and bugs while trying to expose the container directory which is being generated in Dockerfile. Following Docker behavior, it is overwritten by the contents of the folder mounted from the host system. Since an empty folder is mounted, its content replaces the one the folder had when an image was built. From logging inside the Dockerfile I know that files were definitely generated upon image build.

Other authors probably explained in detail how it all works so my advice is just a practical approach. I see an advantage is that both solutions are programmatic and can be executed at some runtime.

1. Comment/remove your mount in `docker-compose.yml`.
2. Run the container to generate files.
3. Get the container ID from `docker ps`.

```
$ container_name="<myca>" # Replace with your container name
$ container_id=$(docker ps --format '{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}' | awk -v name="$container_name" '$2 == name {print $1}')
```

4. Create a symlink with `<symlink_path>`, replacing `<volume_folder>` with the path of the volume folder inside the container:

```
# Get container root directory path
$ container_root=$(sudo docker inspect --format '{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}' <container_id>)
# Create a symlink to any subdirectory or file within the container
$ sudo ln -s "$container_root/</path/to/mount>" <symlink_name>
```

This did not work for me in fact on WSL2 :). I cannot find any of my container files or directories under `/var/lib/docker/overlays2/` or anywhere else specified by `docker inspect`.

So I tried another dumb approach. "The dumber the better" often works with Docker as I notice from my practice.

1. Use Dockerfile to generate files in some temporary directory in your container that will exist after the restart.
2. Add an `entrypoint.sh` script (or a line to it if exists) with the command to copy files on container start. `cp -rf /temp/stored/files/ /path/to/mount/`.
3. After the container is started, directory `/path/to/mount` will be available for the host system.

Also on WSL, you can find bind mounts under `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/`