# Docker mount to folder overriding content

Tags: docker, volume, mount

I have a .net Core web Api having configurations files under a folder called Config.
I created the image and a container from it, and I correctly see using the terminal, that the container contains the folder and the configuration files inside.

My problem is that so far I couldn't find a way to create the same container mounting/binding the Config folder to a physical path, following the requirements:

1) Mount Config folder to a specific host location

2) On container creation, the Config folder should be filled with the files in the image

3) On container creation, override any existing file already present in the folder with those in the image

4) Be able to customize the config files in the folder from the host

My create command:

```
    docker --tls -H="$containerUrl" `
        create `
        --hostname $hostname `
        --name $containerName `
        --mac-address=$containerMacAddress `
        --ip $containerIpAddress `
        --net "bridged-network" `
        --workdir '/app' `
        --mount type=bind,src=$configVolumePath,target=/app/Config `
        --publish "0.0.0.0::80" `
        -t `
        -i $imageName":"$script:buildversion
```

Using **--mount** with type **bind**, as specified in the documentation, if there is any file in the folder, those hare hidden from within the container and the application will see the deployed files.
*The problem of this solution is that I cannot update the files in the config folder from the host.*

Now, removing **type=bind** I get the same result, and it is confusing.

I tried to use volume **--volume $configVolumePath":/app/Config:rw"**, but doing so the pre exising files in the host directory are not overridden and those are the one that will be used within the container.

Additional notes, I don't specify anything in the Dockerfile or compose related to volume mounting, and I didn't try to create a volume to then use it as a source, but I don't think that would make a difference.

The container server is running on a NAS and this is the version:

```
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   781516c
 Built:        Thu Aug  3 16:04:05 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Clearly I'm missing something and I have to learn more about docker, can anyone help?

My references:

1) https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/

2) https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First of all, docker volumes or bind mounts behave like linux mounts.

If the host volume/mount exists and contains files it will "override" whatever is in the container. If not the container files will be mirrored onto the host volume/mount and the container folder and the host will be in sync.
In both cases editing the files on the host will ALWAYS be reflected inside the container.

In your case, you can do the following:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=$configVolumePath \
    --opt o=bind \
    config_vol
```

This will create a volume which will be persisted in $configVolumePath on the host.

When creating the container use that volume:

```
docker create --volume config_vol:/app/Config
```

What you will get is on startup, the host folder will be empty and the files from the image will be "copied" onto the host folder. Editing files in `$configVolumePath` will be reflected inside the container and similarly
files edited inside the container `/app/Config` will be reflected in `$configVolumePath` on the host.

Comment: Thank you yamenk, so my problem was that I wasn't deleting the folder's content.
I tried to create the volume and it behave as you described. To double check that I understood correctly, the actual "pre" creation of the volume is not needed, passing the volume parameters as part of the docker create should be enough, i will try that tonight.

Is there any way, via some --opt parameter to force the deletion/override of the folder content?

Just a note, in order to run the script you suggested i had to use the parameter --name config_vol

Comment: Magnificent! I was looking for the options to pass to the local volume driver and could not find them anywhere for a bind mount!

Comment: HOURS... no... no DAYS wasted trying to find a decent solution to this over the last several years using docker.

Comment: @DerekAdair glad my answer helped :)

Comment: You should submit some of this knowledge to the docker documentation because their docs on using --bind / mounts in general is obtuse (IMO).

Comment: I cant for the life of me even find what different options I can pass via --driver

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167722/1248175) for more details