# Mount a volume without deleting files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use a folder named *tmp* as a volume in docker container in order to do it I am using the following *docker-compose.yml* file

```
version: "3"

services:
  master:
    image: singularities/spark
    command: start-spark master
    hostname: master
    ports:
      - "6066:6066"
      - "7070:7070"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50070:50070"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - "../data:/tmp/"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  worker:
    image: singularities/spark
    command: start-spark worker master
    environment:
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 1
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 4g
    links:
      - master
    volumes:
      - "../data:/tmp/"
```

*tmp* folder exist in singularities/spark image. After I run following command, folders and files under tmp folder are deleted.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker mount to folder overriding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664107/docker-mount-to-folder-overriding-content)

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `docker-compose up -d`, while creating containers docker mounts your `../data` host directory to `/tmp` which cleans up `/tmp` of the image/container & puts everything you have inside `../data` of the host machine.

You might have to choose some other container path other than `/tmp` to ensure it has the data created by `singularities/spark` image.

**EDIT 1**

`docker cp` command can help you copy files FROM/TO host/container.

You want to copy from `/tmp` of the image to host & then copy host to `tmp` (*Not sure why you wanna do this, not suggested & extremely rare scenario* )

However, you can utilize `docker run` with a named volume or a host bind volume to start a container & get the data. Following a `docker cp` to copy data FROM & TO the host or container.

Comment: Is there any way to synchronize data between two side local and container

Comment: Which directory? You can mount it anywhere, make it `../data:/host_data/`. Now you will see your host data in `/host_data` of your container.

Comment: Existing directory like tmp I declared above, I want to put files in tmp to local and copy files in local to tmp

Comment: AFAIU, In that case, you might have to create a Dockerfile with base image as `singularities/spark` for both master & worker . Put everything in the container to some directory by using Dockerfile & do a `cp` or `mv` by using entrypoint scripts to be on the safer side. This question isn't really clarifying the expected behaviour, you can try that out by creating Dockerfile & post your concerns in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

This does only work with single files

```
    volumes:
  - "../data/config.properties:/tmp/config.properties"
```

For example

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the name. The /tmp folder gets cleared at boot time (i.e.at container startup). You'll have to use a different folder name if you want persistent data.