# docker volumes in dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, volume

I want to run my cloud in a docker container and store the data outside the container in a volume. So that when my container is destroyed or removed, the data is still persistent.

When passing the volume parameter at `docker container run -v /path/to/src:/path/to/target imageName:tag` it runs fine without any issues.

How can I pass the `src` and `target` destinations into the dockerfile?

`VOLUME /path/to/target` will create a volume which has its source somewhere in `var/lib/docker` which I do not want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding "VOLUME" instruction in DockerFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935435/understanding-volume-instruction-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Yeah together with Carsons answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Long Answer: what you are trying to do here is essentially against the portability of images. The Docker documentation specifically states this is not possible, as seen here:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

"The host directory is declared at container run-time: The host directory (the mountpoint) is, by its nature, host-dependent. This is to preserve image portability, since a given host directory can’t be guaranteed to be available on all hosts. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from within the Dockerfile. The VOLUME instruction does not support specifying a host-dir parameter. You must specify the mountpoint when you create or run the container."

Comment: Dang I should start reading documentation more carefully :( Thanks a lot man! The portability is one decent argument. Although they COULD still have created that option.

Comment: docker-compose will probably handle a lot of what you're wanting though. You can target a "build <target dockerfile>" instead of an image, or once you have the built image you can specify a volume in the compose. If you're doing orchestration, then it will depend on what you're using there, but every option should have some kind of volume scripting somewhere!

Comment: Are you talking about a host volume with the compose file stuff? That sounds promising. I am learning docker and am "not there yet" since I want to go step by step. I will look forward to that!

Comment: I find Docker docs very dense, but the long and short of it is after you build your image, you can use a compose file to create your containers. In that compose file (docker-compose.yml for example) you can specify volumes using the src:dest method. Highly recommend getting into docker-compose once you're comfy with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want default files in your container, which you can place in the container using the `COPY` directive to copy files from your local machine, into the container image. It is then possible to over-ride the directory you put files in using the `-v` parameter to replace a directory mount with a local-host one when you start/run the container:

eg

```
COPY ./files/source/swagger.json /application/resources/destination/swagger.json
```

see [Docker mount to folder overriding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664107/docker-mount-to-folder-overriding-content) for more