# Basic Docker Bind Mounts Troubleshooting

Tags: python, macos, docker, bind, mount

I'm new to Docker and trying to understand how to use bind mounts with Python scripts.  I'm using a Mac running Catalina (10.15.7).  I have a Python script that I normally start with a local config.ini file containing settings that control the script.  I'd like to run the Python script in a Docker container but have it access the config file from my local machine.

My local directory contains the Dockerfile, requirements.txt file , config.ini file, and a subdirectory (src) with my python files.  The Dockerfile used to build the image is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD ["python", "./main.py" ]
```

After I build the image, I run it with the following command:

```
docker container run -v $(pwd):/app image_name
```

which results in the error *can't open file './main.py'*

Suggestions?

Comment: Docker bind mounts will overwrite the contents of the destination directory on the container. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673246/4676641) for more info. So it seems like the command `python /app/main.py` will fail when the container starts up. Why do you need to mount `$(pwd)` to `/app`? Do you have additional config you need that's not already in the container?

Comment: That's what I suspected was happening.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it'd be useful to run the script with different parameters without needing to rebuild the image.

Comment: One possible solution would be to mount the specific file(s) you want. This might be tedious though. Something like this: `docker container run -v $(pwd)/config.ini:/app/config.ini image_name`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that did work.  I suppose I could also direct the script to look in a folder other than /app for the config.ini file and create a mount there instead.  I've replaced the CMD function with ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile so I can pass an extra argument telling the container where to look for this file.  Haven't quite got it all working yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Docker bind mounts will overwrite the contents of the destination directory on the container. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673246/4676641) for more info. It seems like the command `python /app/main.py` will fail when the container starts up.

Below, I'll just summarize and expand on what I commented.

---

**Mount Specific File(s)**

One possibly quick fix may be to mount a specific file to `/app` for your program to read.

```sh
docker run -v $(pwd)/config.ini:/app/config.ini image_name
```

---

**Run With Environment Variables**

You mentioned creating another mount point to read/mount config from that also may work.

Another option to set things at runtime besides using program arguments from your ENTRYPOINT command is using environment variables. More info in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

```sh
docker run -e "CONFIG_PATH=/app/config/config.ini" image_name
```

---

**Set Environment Variables in Dockerfile**

Of course, you could hard-code some environment variable into your image with `ENV`:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV CONFIG_PATH=/app/config/config.ini
```

Or set it as a build-arg:

```
ARG CONFIG_PATH
ENV CONFIG_PATH=${CONFIG_PATH}
```

And build like so:

```sh
docker build --build-arg CONFIG_PATH=/app/config/config.ini .
```

You may have considered these already or have a better solution, please let me know if I can clarify any of these suggestions. Thanks!