# Why do files disappear when folder is mapped

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the Dockerfile file below:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
LABEL maintainer="campos <joledal387@ncstorms.com>"

# Update the system and install the necessary packages
RUN apt update && apt -y install nano

# Create directory
RUN mkdir /testdir
RUN touch /testdir/file.txt
RUN chmod 777 /testdir/file.txt
VOLUME ["/testdir/"]

# Copy the message "Hello World!"
COPY hello.txt /testdir/file.txt

CMD /bin/bash
```

I create the image from the Dockerfile:

`docker build -t imgtest .`

Then I create three containers. In the first example, when I enter the container, I can see the file.txt file in `/testdir`. In the second example, when mapping the volume `/data /test:/testdir`, I can't see the file.txt file. In the third example, when mapping `/data /var:/var`, I can't see the files in the folder.

Example 1:

```
docker run -d -it --name cont-test-01 --hostname cont-test-01 --restart=always imgtest

docker exec -it cont-test-01 /bin/bash
```

Example 2:

```
docker run -d -it --name cont-test-02 --hostname cont-test-02 --restart=always -v /data/test:/testdir imgtest

docker exec -it cont-test-02 /bin/bash
```

Example 3:

```
docker run -d -it --name cont-test-03 --hostname cont-test-03 --restart=always -v /data/var:/var imgtest

docker exec -it cont-test-03 /bin/bash
```

How can I change the Dockerfile so that files from volumes I created and from system folders like `/var` appear in the container and mapped folder of the docker host?

Answer (score 1):

> In the first example, when I enter the container, I can see the file.txt file in /testdir

So the first example seems to work exactly as you expect it to work.

> In the second example, when mapping the volume /data /test:/testdir, I can't see the file.txt file.

Well that is because you are overwriting the folder:

```sh
$ docker run -d -it --name cont-test-02 --hostname cont-test-02 --restart=always -v /data/test:/testdir imgtest
```

By executing `-v /data/test:/testdir` you are mounting everything under `/data/test` on your host to the container `/testdir`, effectively deleting everything that has been in `/testdir` before that. When using something like `-v /data/test:/testdir2` you would have `/testdir` and `/testdir2` accessible in your container at the same time.

> In the third example, when mapping /data /var:/var, I can't see the files in the folder.

Which files in what folder are you referring to?
As explained above by using `-v /data/var:/var` you are mounting everything from your host `/data/var` to the container `/var`. If you do not see any files inside the containers `/var` than you most likely do not have any files in `/data/var` on your host.
Execute the following on your host and you should see a file called `bar.txt` inside the containers `/var` folder:

```sh
mkdir -p /data/var/
echo "foo" > bar.txt
docker run -d -it --name cont-test-03 --hostname cont-test-03 --restart=always -v /data/var:/var imgtest
```

Answer (score 1):

AS @F1ki said, if you use the default volume feature `-v /source:/target`, the content of target will be replaced with /source. Just new files created by your container after the startup in /target will be available in your /source folder

But if your goal is to **have the already existent and new files** of your container in a folder on your host, you could use a more advanced volume feature:

**volume creation(config_vol)**

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=/data/test \
    --opt o=bind \
    config_vol
```

**use the created volume**

```
docker run -it --name cont-test-04 -v config_vol:/testdir imgtest
```

After that, you could see your **file.txt** in your host folder **/data/test**

I tested with `/var` and I was able to get all its folder/files on my host dir:

[image]

### Tips & docs

- If you use this volume previously attached to a container1, in a new container2, you will not get the container2 folder/files
- Official docker create volume docs

  - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/
  - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- Try to not use volumes or local disk. It will make you dependent of operative system and you will not be able to scale easily.

  - If your concern is logs, try to use graylog, cloudwatch(aws), stackdriver(gcp), etc
  - If your app needs to persist files like photos, reports (xls, pdf, etc), don't use the disk or a database. Use one of the many services that exist like aws S3, etc
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673246/3957754

Comment: I did the test above and it works correctly. After creating the container with the command  `docker volume ls` , I can see the volume `config_vol`. But in some Internet examples, it is not necessary to create a volume when the docker host folder and container folder are mapped. In this case `docker volume ls` returns nothing.

Comment: An example where this occurs: 

`docker run -d --name=cont-db-01  --hostname=cont-db-01 \
-v /data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
--network=db-network \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase \
-e MYSQL_USER=myuser \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=myuser_password \
mysql:5.7`

Comment: I wanted `/testdir` and `/var` to be mounted on the docker host with all their content similar to the example above. How the example mapping works is a mystery to me. I can see everything in `/data/db/mysql`.

Comment: When I remove `config_vol` as `docker volume rm config_vol`, the `/data/test` folder is preserved. Is there any way through docker cli to remove the volume and the folder associated with it?