# Docker image - Volumes cannot be linked

Tags: docker, image, docker-compose, dockerfile, volume

I dockerized my application, so I sent my files in the image with the COPY command in dockerfile

Here my dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress:php7.4-apache
COPY ./site /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wp-content
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS="0"
```

When I use the image with docker-compose and when I link the volume with my local directory I do not recover the files I had sent during the creation of the image

Here my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  ict:
    image: name_of_my_new_image
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
```

Anyone have a solution please?

Comment: A volume mount always hides the contents of the image.  So if you do something like `COPY igAWB.png ./assets/` to include the PNG file from the question in your image, and then mount something else over the container's `assets` directory, you won't see the image's file.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual Dockerfile (and not a PNG file) and the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @David I just edited it.

If I don't mount a volume and if I look in the container directly I can see my files fine. And then if I mount the volume, I don't recover the files and they are no longer in the container

Comment: That's consistent with the way mounting in Unix works in general: mounting anything over a directory hides the content that was already there.

Comment: [Docker mount to folder overriding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664107/docker-mount-to-folder-overriding-content) asks a similar question, though more about config files.  I'd avoid using `volumes:` to hide the code or assets built into an image.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
version: '2'

    services:
       wordpress:
         depends_on:
           - db
         image: wordpress:5.5.0-php7.2-apache
         ports:
           - "8080:80"
         restart: always
         environment:
           WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
           WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rdjbc83
         volumes: 
           - /tmp/wordpress.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/wordpress.ini 
    volumes:
        db_data:
```

Which file you want to mount? I used ini to set my PHP option values.

Comment: I don't directly use the wordpress image but the image I just created with the dockerfile by sending my files in it, it's these same files that I would like to mount but I can't

Comment: @Andriantseheno It will pull image if it can not find it ,no need to worry about that.

Comment: My problem is that I recover the wordpress files well but not the files that I copied in the image. Can be a permission problem or I don't know what

Comment: @Andriantseheno Take a look at my example volumes line. What actaully you want to mount? Which folder? It will apprear in you container.

Comment: I just edited the post and put the code from docker-compose. I would like to mount the /var/www/html volume.

If I use the wordpress image from the hub directly, I recover all these files, but if I use the image I just created, I do not recover any files.