# Serving Django static files in Elasticbeanstalk Docker environment

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying a Django application to EB using docker environment, static files are returning 404.

I'm using gunicorn on docker container, and since it's not recommended/not possible(?) to serve static files via gunicorn, I want to configure EB nginx to serve them using host file-system.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
....
....
# Expose listen ports
EXPOSE 8002

RUN chmod +x ./docker/container_start.sh

CMD ["sh", "./docker/container_start.sh"]
```

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8002"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "ContainerDirectory": "/app/assets",
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/current/assets"
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I tell EB nginx to serve `/assets/`* from `/var/app/current/assets` and to proxy the rest to docker container?

Something like below doesn't work because of the docker environment.

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem! The solution is to customize the nginx configuration in /etc/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf on the server.

Basically I copied the contents of that file into a .ebextension config file and added the location directive for the static folder.

So with your Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8002"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "ContainerDirectory": "/app/assets",
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/current/assets"
    }
  ]
}
```

You would create .ebextension/01_nginx.config

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf":
  mode: 000644
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default        "upgrade";
        ""            "";
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location /assets/ {
          root /var/app/current;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass            http://docker;
            proxy_http_version    1.1;

            proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

That works for me!

Comment: *This answer is not right!* When the host volume is mounted it will mount "over" the contents at the specified directory in container. The contents of that directory will then not be available to the host. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848279/how-to-mount-volume-from-container-to-host-in-docker?rq=1

Comment: Well... you know it does work for me, it’s not just something I’m saying. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it myself and needed to re-engineer things when it didn't work. Are you sure the system is behaving the way you're describing? For instance, I see in your EB Dockerrun config the static dir on the host is `/var/app/current/assets` but in your nginx config the static dir is `/var/current`.

Comment: Perhaps your webapp running in docker is actually serving the static assets itself?

Comment: You are right about the path. That is an error, I've changed the actual paths into generic ones and apparently got this wrong. It should be `/var/app/current/`.

I'll fix edit that right away

Comment: I checked up on it, and those files are served directly from nginx, and not from the application server in the docker container

Comment: Also it is possible to populate a volume with existing container contents: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container

_If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume._

Answer (score 2):

To summarize our solution for serving static files from django running in an elasticbeanstalk docker container with `SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.0 running Docker`:

1. We don't want to run `collectstatic` until our container is really ready to go.  To that end we kick it off in our entrypoint.sh, which also starts gunicorn shortly afterwards.
2. We let `collectstatic` drop the static files in "static" From our settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "static"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

3. We configure a post-deployment script in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy` that copies the static files out of the container and onto the ec2 vm in `/var/app/current` (where the script runs):

```
#! /bin/bash
docker cp $(docker ps --no-trunc -q | head -n 1):/home/app/static .
```

4. We tell nginx where to find the static files by dropping a custom configuration file in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/custom.conf` :

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/app/current/;
}
```

That's it.  It works for us.

Comment: just needed to change `/home/app/static` else worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do isn't possible.

You cannot mount a `/host-dir` onto a `/container-dir` and expect the host to read the contents of `/container-dir` which existed before mounting. (The contents of `/container-dir` are hidden.) See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848279/how-to-mount-volume-from-container-to-host-in-docker?rq=1).

You probably want to include your static assets inside your Elastic Beanstalk bundle rather than inside your docker image. If you do that those assets will appear in `/var/app/current` and you can then tell Elastic Beanstalk's built in `nginx` to serve them as [per the other answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54703075/273637).

Comment: It is possible to populate a volume with existing container contents: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container _If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents are copied into the volume._

Comment: @SuneKjærgård in the doc you link to, it explains that the container will populate _the new volume_ with the content's of the directory--which can then be shared between other _containers_. However, it will *not* replace the contents of _a directory on your host_ which you've mounted as "shared" onto your container.

Comment: @SuneKjærgård here's the output of my terminal where I try to demonstrate my point explicitly: https://gist.github.com/topher515/e56430e7e0c12c2aa8b5aa30eb24bc97