# Using A Mounted Volume To Copy A Directory From Docker Container To Host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I build a docker image with the following docker file

```
FROM alpine:edge
ARG ciUser=bamboo

RUN apk --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ add \
 nodejs nodejs-npm chromium firefox xwininfo xvfb dbus eudev ttf-freefont fluxbox libc6-compat

WORKDIR /opt/systac
RUN adduser -u 500 -g 500 -s /bin/bash -h /opt/systac -D $ciUser
USER $ciUser

COPY ./package.json /opt/systac/package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json /opt/systac/package-lock.json

RUN npm install \
    && npm cache clean --force \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

ENV NODE_PATH=/opt/systac/node_modules

USER root
COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/systac/
COPY ./cucumber.js /opt/systac/
COPY ./ListAllFiles.js /opt/systac/
RUN chmod +x /opt/systac/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENV SCREEN_WIDTH=1280
ENV SCREEN_HEIGHT=720

VOLUME ["/opt/systac/e2e"]
USER $ciUser
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/systac/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [ "npm", "run", "e2e-test"]
```

I build the docker image like so

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg ciUser=bamboo -t bhreinb/workmate .
```

and then I run it within a docker container with the objective of disposing the image once I run it

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/e2e/:/opt/systac/e2e bhreinb/systac
```

as part of running the entry point command which happens to be a NPM script a folder gets generated as part of that process in the container. It gets wrote to location `/opt/systac/results`

I would like that directory to be copied back to the host so that I can report on this (namely we have html, log files etc wrote in that output directory)

I seen this post which may accomplish my objectives but unfortunately this didn't work for me

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848279/how-to-mount-volume-from-container-to-host-in-docker/52167722#52167722
```

Any help on the above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you bind-mount another host directory there (another `docker run -v`) option?

Comment: I assume you mean like this `docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/e2e/:/opt/systac/e2e -v $PWD/results/:/opt/systac/results/ bhreinb/systac` (unfortunately this doesn't work, in that results folder doesn't populated)