# Ubuntu mount docker volume into system

Tags: docker, mount, ubuntu-18.04

We have a docker container with a folder in /usr/local/lib.

From an application in the host system (not in docker), we want to read the files of the container.

We only can find information about the inverse case (mount system file into docker container).

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848279/how-to-mount-volume-from-container-to-host-in-docker?rq=1

Comment: Besides the volume mounting, you can also `docker cp` or check the container runtime directory. There are a bunch of options here. Check the Docker documentation for more information.

Comment: It seems it is a open issue in docker, You can see the issue and some solutions [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26872)

Comment: I am wondering why this question is downvoted? Lack of information? Just downvote if there is no possible answer or someone doesn't know the anwser?

Comment: @M.Fooladgar thanks for the link. A lot of information there. It seems there is nothing "native" yet.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is not possible. You can however export the filesystem of a container:

```
docker container export {container_name} > container.tar
```

You can then investigate that.

Hope this answers your question