# Docker: write files from container to a volume on host machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to write files from my web application (hosted on a docker container) to a volume on my host Ubuntu machine. I ran the command `docker run -v /space-storage:/space-storage img-captain-webapplication:29` where the first `/space-storage` is the folder on my host machine, the second `/space-storage` is the folder on my image and `img-captain-webapplication:29` is the name of the image(corresponding to the container).

[image]

When I upload a file to the /space-storage` folder on my container, it does not show as a file on the host machine.

**Host machine folder:**

[image: Host machine folder]

**Folder created on container:**
[image: Folder created on container]

What am I missing?

**Update 1:**
Thank you @tentative for your input.
I ran the `ls ~/space-storage` on the host machine and it was the correct folder.
So I ran `docker RUN -v target=~/space-storage,source=/space-storage img-captain-webapplication:29` command on the host machine, then created a file in spaces-storage folder on the container(I ran the `ls /space-storage/10445075-b1da-46eb-9d18-6e85b427fdef` command on the container to check that the folder had a file) and it still did not show on the ~/space-storage folder on the host machine.

Comment: It looks like you're running `ls` in your home directory but you mounted the directory with an absolute path of `/storage-space`. Try running `ls /storage-space` on your host machine since that's the folder you're mounting.

Comment: Additionally, [please do not post images of your code/commands](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Commands should be posted as text. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was an answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848279/how-to-mount-volume-from-container-to-host-in-docker) and I will have to remove my answer since it's incomplete.

Comment: If you need the data off the container, you can start the container and then run `docker cp CONTAINER_NAME:/storage-space ~/storage-space` to get the data off. Off the top of my head, you could just then run the image again with this mounted folder on if you want to keep the data in sync with the container. The linked answer has other more involved solutions.