# How to mount docker container with host to view the config of container in mounted host folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have docker image that runs the products within it successfully with a given set of configuration in the config folder of the container. Now the team would like to view the config folder/files within the container outside of the container i.e. in the host folder . I use the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 
    -v /opt/docker/config:/opt/components/DISTRIBUTOR/config \
    --name distributor --env-file file.env -d distributor
```

Expected : The host folder is empty initially before running the above command and I am expecting the content of config folder of the container to be displayed in the host folder after the execution of the above command.

Actual :  On running of the above command, the config folder in the container becomes empty as the host folder and fails to start the server.

How to mount the volume to view folder/files from container to host (even if in Read only mode) without impacting the files/folders in the container ? Host to container works fine, but that's not what I am looking at.

Comment: Here is a good advice for your usecase. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167722/4486909

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova, it worked for me.....superb!!!! .... Now i am able to modify the configuration as well from the local...thanks in tons